# How do I refer to a child class variable from an inherited parent class method in PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, methods

Say I have two classes:

```
class ParentClass
{
     public function getSomething()
     {
         return $this->variable_name;
     }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    private $variable_name = 'something specific to child class';
    ...
}
```

Then I call code to instantiate the `ChildClass` and call the inherited `getSomething()` method:

```
$object = new ChildClass();
$value = $object->getSomething();
```

When I call that last line, it gives me an error because `$variable_name` does not exist in `ParentClass`. I'm expecting `ChildClass` to inherit the method `getSomething()`, but I understand that since it is not overridden explicitly in `ChildClass`, it uses the parent's scope when running the parent version of the method.

How can I most efficiently have the `ChildClass` inherit the method *and* give it the ability to read the child class's `$variable_name` when said method is called?

Comment: Just make it protected rather than private. Private means it belongs to that class and that class only (no inheritance): https://eval.in/572905 vs https://eval.in/572906

Comment: what if some child class does not have this variable? what parent should do?

Comment: I'd have a check for the existence of the variable, of course. And thanks for the comment, Robbie. I completely missed that.

Comment: this is not how OOP works, you should not check for variables in child classes and in many other languages you will not be able to do this without hacks, you should think in terms of interfaces/contracts and method/actions, forget about variables for moment

Comment: I'll give some thought as to how to differently approach this problem. I admit, I have little formal training in OOP in PHP and have learned most of it on the job (salaried and freelancing alike). I felt stupid even asking this question, because I knew there was something I was missing. Thank for you for being patient!

Comment: @RobbieAverill just don't forget to enable error reporting to see `Notice: Undefined property: ParentClass::$variable_name in /tmp/execpad-7500a03f3320/source-7500a03f3320 on line 9`

Comment: @TerranRich if your child property is *protected*, not private, then you can do `isset($this->my_property)` inside the parent class, assuming you've instantiated the child class rather than the parent directly.

Answer (score 3):

> Rule of thumb: if your parent class needs to know anything about child classes, then you do something wrong.

When you design classes or interfaces you should first think about `actions` (methods) which they can perform. Don't think about their `internal state` (variables).

To solve your particular problem, you should first decide, whether you need to have different object states or different actions.

For different states, you could implement something like this:

```
class ParentClass {
    private $variable;
    function __construct($var) {
        $this->variable = $var;
    }
    function getSomething() {
        return $this->variable;
    }
}
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('something specific to child class');
    }
}
```

so, variable is part of Parent's state and child object must init it.

another approach is to make contract:

```
abstract class ParentClass {
    function getSomething() {
        return $this->internalGetSomething();
    }
    abstract function internalGetSomething();
}
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    function internalGetSomething() {
        return 'something specific to child class';
    }
}
```

so, internalGetSomething is contract between parent and child

Comment: I disagree with this statement. Your second example as well as using interfaces in the children is a perfect example of where parents will know exactly what child classes will do. Agreed, it shouldn't be accessing properties but rather methods

Comment: @robbie-averill no, parent declares contract, which must be followed by children. Probably this particular example is not very good to illustrate concept. But here we have concrete question

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

Long answer: That's not how OO works. Parent classes doesn't know your childs.
What you can do is to use Reflection, but it's not the way to go, you need to rethink your project.

```
class Parent {
    public function getSomething(Child $child) {
        $reflection = new ReflectionObject($child);
        $variable_name = $r->getProperty('variable_name');
        $variable_name->setAccessible(true);
        return $variable_name->getValue($child);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like you stated, the ChildClass inherits from the ParentClass, not the other way around. To the ParentClass, `$this->variable_name` is an unknown variable. A simple way that I would suggest would be to change the ParentClass method a bit and override it in the ChildClass as such:

```
class ParentClass
{
    public function getSomething($param)
    {
        return $param;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    private $variable_name = 'something specific to child class';

    public function getSomething($param = "")
    {
        return parent::getSomething($param = $this->variable_name);
    }
}

$object = new ChildClass();
$value = $object->getSomething();
echo $value;
```